# Calling an ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcomponent, actionevent

I am in the process of learning and creating a custom JButton/Component. I have the most of what I need, except I do not know how to call actionPerformed on my ActionListners.

Code:

```
package myProjects;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LukeButton extends JComponent{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Luke");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        LukeButton lb = new LukeButton();
        lb.addActionListener(e->{
            System.out.println("Success");
        });
        frame.add(lb);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

private final ArrayList<ActionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();

public LukeButton(){

}
public void addActionListener(ActionListener e){
    listeners.add(e);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    Shape rec = new Rectangle2D.Float(10, 10, 60, 80);

    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g2.draw(rec);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.fill(rec);
}
}
```

Does anyone one know how to call the "listeners" ArrayList once the button is clicked? Thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over your list of `ActionListener`s and call their `actionPerformed` method, something like...

```
protected void fireActionPerformed() {
    if (!listeners.isEmpty()) {

        ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "LukeButton");
        for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.actionPerformed(evt);
        }

    }
}
```

Now, you need to define the actions which might trigger a `ActionEvent` to occur, mouse click, key press etc and the call the `fireActionPerformed` method when they occur

Have a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details