# How can I size my custom component appropriately?

Tags: java, swing

So I have a custom Button, that runs good, no errors.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LukeButton extends JComponent implements MouseListener{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Luke");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        LukeButton lb = new LukeButton();
        lb.addActionListener(e->{
            System.out.println("Success");
        });
        frame.add(lb, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
//ArrayList of listeners
private final ArrayList<ActionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();

public LukeButton(){
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}
//Adds a listeners to the list
public void addActionListener(ActionListener e){
    listeners.add(e);
}
//Called when button is provoked
public void fireActionListeners(){
    if(!listeners.isEmpty()){
        ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "LukeButton");
        for(ActionListener l: listeners){
            l.actionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }
}
//Listens for click on my component
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    fireActionListeners();
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(100, 100);
}
//Draws my button
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    Shape rec = new Rectangle2D.Float(10, 10, 60, 80);

    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g2.draw(rec);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.fill(rec);
}
//Methods that must be over written.
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
}
}
```

Here is my main problem- when ever I click ANYWHERE on the JFrame, it says the button was clicked, but the only part I want to have the action listener on is the blue rectangle I have on the JFrame. (You'll under stand my issue if you run my program) Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks for taking your time to read :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `mousePressed` method so that it first checks to see if the Point of clicking is enclosed by the blue rectangle. A simple if block is all that is needed. Note: do not create your Rectangle inside of paintComponent. If it is a constant, declare and create it in the class so that it can be used in the `mousePressed` method. Also note that Rectangle2D has a `contains(...)` method that will help you **very** much. Also note that MouseEvent has a `getPoint()` method that will also help you **very** much.

Also, to size your button, override its `getPreferredSize()` method as was recommended by me in your [previous recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002025/calling-an-actionevent). Also, avoid calling `setSize()` on your JFrame or on any component. Also, `pack()` your JFrame before showing it.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about either of those methods. Of coarse I still have a little problems to solve, but I'll just leave that to my self :)